# Are there reasons to not mix units in CSS?

Tags: css, units-of-measurement

When doing responsive designs I often need to have a percentage margin horizontally, but vertically I usually don't want to have percentage, but rather fixed pixels.

Are there any reasons why I shouldn't be mixing units in my margins and paddings like this:

```
margin: 10px 10%;
```

Browser performance? Cross browser rendering issues?

Answer (score 4):

As long as you're maintaining that vertical is pixel based and horizontal is percentage based, you should be fine. Just don't mix the two (at least not within a single element), or you'll get undesired effects across the board.

Comment: Hege - I agree with Kory here. You should be fine unless you use two different units in the same direction.

Comment: I am not sure if my comment is irrelevant, but whats your thought about crossbrowser units? I face different behaviour in td width in firefox and chrome with same value of width in pixels.